# JST 2-PIN pin order for power supply

Tags: connector, pinout

is there any *non-written* convention for pinout of JST connector (2-pin) when used for power supply or can I freely invert +/- wires based on my specific convience?

Answer (score 0):

They're used alot on drone LiPo batteries, so maybe follow that "convention".  Probably about as close as you'll get to one.